# Force node where all filters of a pipe execution must run

Tags: spring, spring-xd

I need to control where the filters of a pipe are executed in such a way that all filters of a pipeline are run on the same node as the first filter of that pipeline.

For an example:

Let's say I have filters f1..f10 of a pipeline p1. And I have 10 nodes n1..n10. 
Now assume XD choses a node n5 to run filter f1 on. How do I enforce all subsequent filters f2..10 to run on the same node n5?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure each container to be assigned to specific groups and when you deploy a stream, you can specify a criteria for the deployment of each module (e.g. that the container must be in a particular group).

See [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/1.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#deployment).

Comment: Thanks. Ut would however help me a lot if you coukd make a minimal example how to do this. I'm new to XD and I don't get how to configure the container after a first filter was invoked.

Comment: You assign a group (or any attribute you want) to a container in its servers.yml file ([see here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/1.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#container-attributes)); you can then use those attributes in the deployment criteria. You have to set up the deployment criteria for all modules, including the first; you can use `module.*.criteria=...` to use the same criteria for all modules in the stream. The criteria must uniquely identify a container if you want all modules on a single instance.

Comment: So if I assign an attribute invocationId_x to a container, I could later use something like "module.fooJob.criteria=attributes.contains('invocationId_x')" as part of the deployment criteria?